# How can I select from in other select in MYSQL query?

Tags: mysql

How can I select from in other select in MYSQL query?
Something like this

```
SET @row_number = 0;

SELECT a.num FROM

(SELECT 
    (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, id
FROM
    main) as a where a.id=6
```

I want to know the number of records where id=6 if it's the first row, second row or third one

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: "I want to know the number of record where id=6" **clear** "if it's the first row, second row or third one" **unclear**

Answer (score 1):

If your query has the filter `where a.id = 6`, then the row with id = 6 will always be the first row of the result set.

I am interpreting your question to mean:  "if I sorted by id ascending, what row number is the row with id = 6 going to be on".  If so, you can use a simple aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM main m
WHERE m.id <= 6;
```

Your query seems inspired by enumerating all the rows.  You could do this version as well:

```
select m.*
from (select m.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
      from main m cross join
           (select @rn := 0) params
      order by id
     ) m
where id = 6;
```

The first version should be more efficient, particularly with an index on `id`.

Comment: I'd add `ORDER BY m.id ASC`, just to be safe.

Comment: @rickdenhaan . . . That has absolutely not relevance in the first query.  It is an aggregation query that returns one row.